# Multi target framework issue -> Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Runtime" that could not be resolved

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution that is based on netcore 3.1 (some dll, some WPF apps) that is working properly . I decided to try to make it target also net48 to be able in some particular cases to use some third party API currently not compatible with netcore.

I changed my projects to files with the following line

```xml
 <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

I changed all the c#8 code parts.

And I put one application for test in net48 to see if everything goes ok.

When I launch my application, it crashes instantly complaining about System.Runtime version 4.2.2.0 not being found.

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I look in the output log of the build I have some warning about conflicts in resolution of System.Runtime (4.1.2.0 vs 4.2.2.0)

For exemple :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB3277 Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Runtime" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
    "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
    References which depend on "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.dll].
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades\System.Runtime.dll".
            System.Runtime
    References which depend on "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
        C:\Users\alex\.nuget\packages\system.io.pipelines\4.5.1\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Pipelines.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\alex\.nuget\packages\system.io.pipelines\4.5.1\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Pipelines.dll".
            C:\Users\alex\.nuget\packages\system.io.pipelines\4.5.1\ref\netstandard1.3\System.IO.Pipelines.dll
            C:\Users\alex\.nuget\packages\fubardev.ftpserver\3.1.2\lib\net47\FubarDev.FtpServer.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureCore.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureAutomation\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureAutomation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureVision\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureVision.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleBase\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleBase.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleDefinitionsManagement\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleDefinitionsManagement.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogger\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogger.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogin\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogin.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleNavigation\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleNavigation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\BaseClassesFw\bin\Debug\net48\BaseClassesFw.dll
        C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\Syncfusion.Themes.MaterialDarkFW.WPF.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\Syncfusion.Themes.MaterialDarkFW.WPF.dll".
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureCore.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureAutomation\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureAutomation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureVision\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureVision.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleBase\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleBase.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleDefinitionsManagement\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleDefinitionsManagement.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogger\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogger.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogin\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogin.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleNavigation\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleNavigation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\BaseClassesFw\bin\Debug\net48\BaseClassesFw.dll
        C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\Syncfusion.Themes.MaterialLightFW.WPF.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\Syncfusion.Themes.MaterialLightFW.WPF.dll".
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureCore\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureCore.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureAutomation\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureAutomation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\InfrastructureVision\bin\Debug\net48\InfrastructureVision.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleBase\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleBase.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleDefinitionsManagement\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleDefinitionsManagement.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogger\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogger.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleLogin\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleLogin.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\ModuleNavigation\bin\Debug\net48\ModuleNavigation.dll
            C:\Dev\csharp\Demo1\BaseClassesFw\bin\Debug\net48\BaseClassesFw.dll BaseClasses C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2302
```

After doing some research I have tried :

- To install a more recent version of System.Runtime nuget package in all my projects ( I cannot found System.Runtime 4.2.2.0 by the way)
- To modify the app.config of my test app with some binding redirection

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

- To play with the AutoGenerateBindingRedirects option

But the error is still the same. Note that if I roll back the test app to netcore everything is working fine.

Do I need to try to find another version of the packages that gives the warning (and hope that I can find one that fits) or is there another way to "force" my app to use a given version ?